# Why this dates comparison returns false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

```
irb> updated_at = "2014-03-18 13:05"
irb> updated_at.to_datetime.between?("2014-03-01","2014-03-18")
=> false
```

The date `2014-03-18 13:05` is between the dates `2014-03-01` and `2014-03-18`, so why `between?` returns `false`?

Comment: Are you in Ruby ? or Rails? In pure Ruby how you didn't get *no method* error when you tried `updated_at.to_datetime` ?

Answer (score 4):

`DateTime` is a measure of a date and time within that day.

When you specify just the date, the time element is assumed to be midnight (i.e. the earliest possible time in that day.)  For example:

```
irb(main):012:0> DateTime.parse("2014-03-18")
=> #<DateTime: 2014-03-18T00:00:00+00:00 (4913469/2,0/1,2299161)>
```

You can see in the above output that it is midnight.

If you were to change your test to be the 19th of March instead of the 18th then the it would return `true`.

You can use the following to test within two dates inclusively without regard to the time of day:

```
updated_at.to_datetime.between?("2014-03-01", "2014-03-18".to_datetime.end_of_day)
```

Comment: One question - `between?("2014-03-01","2014-03-18")`.. Can you compare *date* object with *string* objects ?

Comment: Post is tagged in *Ruby*.. How you are answering in *Rails* ?

Comment: Ruby On rails date comparision in if condition

Comment: @user2903300 Why you didn't tag the question properly.. Then ?

Comment: I am new to the stack overflow thats why?

Comment: @ArupRakshit My answer was actually not specific to Rails up until the Rails tag was added.

Comment: @DonCruickshank It of-course. As per the tag, First question should be to OP that - *how do you able to use method `to_datetime`* in Ruby?